# read out a txt and send the last line to email adress - vbscript

Tags: vbscript, wsh, text-files

Hallo,

I'm back haha :-) so i have the next question and i hope someone can help me...
I know i have a lot of questions but i will try to learn vbscript :-)

Situation:
This script read out (every 5 min) the last line of a txt and send it to my eMail Address.

Problem:
I'll check the txt all 5 min, but at the moment every 5 min there comes a mail. I'll try to get only a new mail, when there is something new in the txt.

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso, WshShell, Text, Last, objEmail

Const folder = "C:\test.txt"

Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do
    Text = Split(fso.OpenTextFile(Datei, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLF)
    Letzte = Text(UBound(Text))
                       Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
                    objEmail.From = "test@test.com"
                    objEmail.To = "test@test.com"
                    objEmail.Subject = "Control" 
                    objEmail.Textbody = Last
                    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
                        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
                    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
                        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _
                            "smtpip" 
                    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
                        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
                    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
                    objEmail.Send

                    WScript.Sleep 300000
Loop
```

Can someone help me?

Sry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso, WshShell, Text, Last, objEmail, linecount

Const folder = "C:\test.txt"
linecount = 0

Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do
    Text = Split(fso.OpenTextFile(Datei, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLF)
    if UBound(Text) > linecount Then
         linecount = UBound(Text)
         Letzte = Text(UBound(Text))
                       Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
                    objEmail.From = "test@test.com"
                    objEmail.To = "test@test.com"
                    objEmail.Subject = "Control" 
                    objEmail.Textbody = Last
                    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
                        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
                    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
                        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _
                            "smtpip" 
                    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
                        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
                    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
                    objEmail.Send
     End If

                    WScript.Sleep 300000
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you only get one mail is because of the UBound, which only gets you the last element of the array.

To send a mail for each line, you will have to remember the upper bound after sending the mails and then loop over the lines

```
Option Explicit 

Dim fso, WshShell, Text, Last, objEmail 

Const folder = "C:\test.txt" 

Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

dim index = 1

Do 
    Text = Split(fso.OpenTextFile(Datei, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLF) 
    Letzte = Text(UBound(Text)) 

                WScript.Sleep 300000 

for i = index to UBound(Text) 
                   Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
                objEmail.From = "test@test.com" 
                objEmail.To = "test@test.com" 
                objEmail.Subject = "Control"  
                objEmail.Textbody = Last 
                objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
                    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
                objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
                    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _ 
                        "smtpip"  
                objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
                    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
                objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update 
                objEmail.Send 
Next 

index = UBound(Text) 

Loop
```

Comment: every 5 minutes it comes a mail with the last line of the test.txt! My Problem is now, i will only have a mail when there is something new in the txt. So i will check the txt all 5 minutes and if there something new in it (only the last line), i will have a mail. I'm sry for my english. 

keyword timestamp for example

Comment: thanks, but its the same problem all 5 minutes i became a mail...but i will only get a mail when there is a new line in the txt...